# how can i trasfere data object to an array

Tags: reactjs, react-native

hey there i have a small question i have data base in firebase that look like that

```
{ 
 0001: {
      name : ....,
      image: .... 
     },
 0002: {
       name: .... , 
       image: ...
    }
}
```

i want to use it with flat list but when i use object.values to transfer data i lost my id and also object.entries didnt give me anything
Object.values(data); 
 there is any way to create an array from this data like that ?

```
 {id ,
  name ,
  image}
```

and put it in my flat list beacause i want when to click on a item open new windows and send that `id` 
the `id` should be the key number `0001` `0002` ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce`
https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```
Object.keys(data).reduce((result, key) => {
  return result.concat({id: key, ...data[key]})
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

another way if you need:

```
Object.values(data).map((obj, i) => ({ id: Object.keys(data)[i], ...obj}));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Object.entries(data)`
will return `an array of [key, value] pairs`

```
var data = { 
 0001: {
      name : "",
      image: "" 
     },
 0002: {
       name: "" , 
       image: ""
    }
}
```

then try to call

```
Object.entries(data)
```